# Creating composite figure from matplotlib animation frames

Tags: animation, matplotlib, latex, eps

I have a data time-series that I am animating with matplotlib, and I would like to add frames by a specific time interval (e.g. monthly) to subplots in a matplotlib figure, so that I can have better control over the axes, etc. The end goal is having a one-page series of images depicting the animation.

[image]
[Images source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Location_map_North_Atlantic)

Is there a way of doing this?

If not, is there at least a way to force it to save the frames .eps for better quality when compiling them together to import into a latex document?

**Update:**

I found that you are able to [pickle Basemap objects](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/blob/master/examples/hires.py) (also discussed on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11550675/943773)), and apparently as of matplotlib 13.01 [figures are pickle-able](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/whats_new.html) (experimental). I suppose you could pickle the instance of each desired frame and then subsequently load them to subplots. I will post my result once I've had time to try this out.